# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, django

In my **models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def domain(self):
        long_url = urlparse(self.url).netloc if self.url else "hello"
        return long_url.split('.', 1)[1] if long_url.split('.', 1)[0] == 'www' else long_url
```

but I've decided to remove "hello" so I changed to None.

Now I get the error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

any help please...

Comment: `None` stored inside long_url

Comment: `long_url` is `None`

Comment: @danidee yes but how do I not display anything if it's not self.url

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes but how do I not display anything if it's not self.url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `long_url` can be null since your model accepts it to be so. Add a null check before doing the split.

```
return long_url.split('.', 1)[1] if (long_url and long_url.split('.', 1)[0] == 'www') else long_url
```

should work.

Comment: so how do I solve this issue? I can see long_url can be null if I use None but isn\t there a way to make it None??

Comment: My Code will return `None` if long_url is `None`. I believe that's what you want?

Comment: with this code I get (None), I don't want anything to be displayed if it's not self.url

Comment: sorry my goal was to not display it at all

Comment: What do you mean by display? Returning None from a function is equivalent to an empty line (you can handle this in the view maybe?) If you want to return a string, just initialize `long_url = ""` instead of `None` in the first line. Eg :

Comment: I mean display nothing, right now it shows (None) but I don't want anything to be shown. by none I meant literally None

Comment: Tried putting `""` instead of `None`/`hello` in the first line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105865/discussion-between-sudhanshu-shekhar-and-winixxee).